# Android not picking up the landscape layout after the device orientaion change

Tags: android, layout, orientation, qualifiers

I have created an app which have a help screen(designed in a separate layout file) open by the 3-dots icon. When I open it portrait mode by pressing 3-dots menu icon the android selects the portrait layout file but when I changes the device's orientation the android still loads the portrait layout file.It is not loading the landscape layout.Although I have created the landscape layout file with qualifiers as sw320-land and portrait layout as sw320. Someone please help me out with this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- Check in your manifest if you setted android:screenOrientation="portrait" on this activity and remove it

2- If you don't care about screen size put all your landscape layouts into layout-land

Comment: the help screen is not an activity, it's only a layout xml

Comment: I know but you have to try this two way

Comment: activity android:name=".GameActivity2108" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Ok, now go to the second step. Put your layout into layout-land directory instead of sw320-land